# To find solution of $y''(x)=ay^3(x)+by^2(x)+cy(x)+d$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, elliptic-functions, elliptic-integrals

We know that
$$g'(x)=g(x)$$
$g(0)=1$
Then $g(x)=e^x$

If we want to solve $y'=ay$,

We can write general solution $y'=ay$ (or if derivative both sides $y''=a^2y$)
 $$y=k.g(a x)=k.e^{ax}$$
 where $k$ is a constant.

We can express particular solution of many differential equation via using $e^{\beta x}$ but some we cannot.
For example, we can find a particular solution for

$y'=1+y^2$  (if we apply derivative both sides then we get  $y''=2y^3+2y$)

and particular solution for $y''=2y^3+2y$ can be written: $$y=\tan(x)=-i\frac{g(ix)-g(-ix)}{g(ix)+g(-ix)}=-i\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}$$

but as I have known that we cannot solve the general differential equation ,$y''(x)=ay^3(x)+by^2(x)+cy(x)+d$  (where a,b,c are constants) via only using  $e^{\beta x}$ . We need to define some non-elementery functions (elliptic functions) to find the solution. I thought to select an elliptic function to find a particular solution of general differential equation ,$$y''(x)=ay^3(x)+by^2(x)+cy(x)+d$$ by using the selected elliptic function and elementary function $e^{\beta x}$ (my aim to find a closed form with limited terms in combination of both functions or only with the selected elliptic function).

Let's select an elliptic function and try to use it a base function for this aim.

$$f''(x)=-2f^3(x)$$
$f(0)=0$

$f'(0)=1$

$$(f'(x))^2=1-f^4(x)$$
The defined base function can be expressed
$$x= \int_{0}^{f(x)} \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^4}}$$

Euler found an addition formula for this selected $f(x)$. [The formula at page 6 in article](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/mathjournal/archives/2009/vol10-n2/paper2/v10n2-2pd.pdf) that was written by Jose Barrios

$$f(x+y)=\frac{f(x)\sqrt{1-f^4(y)}+f(y)\sqrt{1-f^4(x)}}{1+f^2(x)f^2(y)}$$

or we can rewrite it as:

$$f(x+y)=\frac{f(x)f'(y)+f(y)f'(x)}{1+f^2(x)f^2(y)}$$

Is it possible to find a particular solution of the general differential equation $y''=ay^3+by^2+cy+d$ by using the combination of the selected  elliptic function $f(x)$  and $e^{x}$ in a closed form ?

Note:Maybe we need to select another base $f(x)$ that would be easier for this aim. I selected randomly.

I need references and hints about this idea.
Thanks a lot for your helps

EDIT:  15th August ,2016

I would like to  share my results:

Let's assume that we have the equation:

$$ y'=\frac{dy}{dx} = p (y^2 + my + n)$$

If we solve the differential equation:

General solution of the differential equation can be written as

$y=-\frac{m}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{m^2-4n}}{2}+\cfrac{\sqrt{m^2-4n}}{1+ke^{xp\sqrt{m^2-4n}}}$

where $k$ is a constant.

If we derivative both side
$$ y'=\frac{dy}{dx} = p (y^2 + my + n)$$
$$ y''=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = p (2y + m)y'$$
$$ y''= p^2 (2y + m)(y^2 + my + n)$$

$$ y''= 2p^2y^3+3p^2my^2+p^2(m^2+2n)y+p^2mn$$

If we compare with our general equation , We can find a condition that it has solution via $e^{\beta x}$.

$$y''= ay^3+by^2+cy+d$$

The condition:
$$2b^3+27a^2d=9abc$$

If the general equation satisfy this condition , the general equation has a solution with $e^{\beta x}$ but if the condition is not satisfy , we should express the solution with elliptic functions. It is a known fact that elliptic functions cannot be expressed by $e^{\beta x}$ in closed form.

$p=\sqrt{a/2}$ ; $m=\frac{2b}{3a}$;$n=\frac{3d}{b}$

$y_p(x)=-\frac{m}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{m^2-4n}}{2}+\cfrac{\sqrt{m^2-4n}}{1+ke^{xp\sqrt{m^2-4n}}}$
where $k$ is a constant.

I have noticed that we can express the solvable condition as:

$y_p=A\cfrac{e^{\alpha x} +B}{e^{\alpha x} +C}$

Let's transform the general diff equation

$y=A\cfrac{u +B}{u +C}$ and to check a condition for u

$$y'=A\cfrac{C-B}{(u +C)^2}u'$$

$$y''= ay^3+by^2+cy+d$$
If we integrate both side, we get: $$ \frac12 \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2 =  \frac{a}{4} y^4+\frac{b}{3} y^3+\frac{c}{2} y^2+d y + e$$  where $e$ is a constant.

$$  \frac{A^2(C-B)^2}{2(u +C)^4} u'^2 =  \frac{a}{4}\frac{(u +B)^4}{(u +C)^4}+\frac{b}{3} \frac{(u +B)^3}{(u +C)^3}+\frac{c}{2} \frac{(u +B)^2}{(u +C)^2}+d \frac{(u +B)}{(u +C)} + e$$

$$ \frac{A^2(C-B)^2}{2} u'^2=  \frac{a}{4}(u +B)^4+\frac{b}{3} (u +B)^3(u +C)+\frac{c}{2} (u +B)^2(u +C)^2+d (u +B)(u +C)^3 + e(u +C)^4$$

I have been looking for a condition if we can transform it to one equation
such as

$$ u'^2=  a_4u^4+a_3u^3+a_2u^2+a_1u+a_0$$

where $a_n$ is any selected constant.

In my question , I selected to convert it to

$$ u'^2=  s(1-u^4)$$

but I am not sure if we can transform the general equation into this type.

Can anybody prove that it is possible or not to convert it to a selected form such as $ u'^2=  a_4u^4+a_3u^3+a_2u^2+a_1u+a_0$?
(where $a_n$ are selected constants.)

EDIT:7th Sep 2016

$$ \frac{A^2(C-B)^2}{2} u'^2=  \frac{a}{4}(u +B)^4+\frac{b}{3} (u +B)^3(u +C)+\frac{c}{2} (u +B)^2(u +C)^2+d (u +B)(u +C)^3 + e(u +C)^4$$

If We select $e=-(\frac{a}{4}+\frac{b}{3}+\frac{c}{2}+d)$ then $u^4$ term is canceled so we can get 3 degree polynomial form.

$$ \frac{A^2(C-B)^2}{2} u'^2= b_3 u^3+b_2u^2+b_1u+b_0$$

We can do $x=\alpha t$ then  we can get the form,

$$  u'^2=  u^3+k_2(A,B,C)u^2+k_1(A,B,C)u+k_0(A,B,C)$$

We still have 3 parameters ($A,B,C$) to select . We can transform into a selected form $ u'^2=  u^3+a_2u^2+a_1u+a_0$. (where $a_n$ are  selected constants.)

Can anybody help me to show if the transform to a selected form $ u'^2=  u^3+a_2u^2+a_1u+a_0$  is possible or not? 
Thanks a lot for helps

Comment: BTW to be a bit more specific: Is the goal to find (all) the elliptic integrals which gives rise to some explicit solution involving say $e^{ax}$ and, say radicals/rational functions, i.e. expressable by elementary functions? Or the ones for which there is a non-elementary solution $f$ and the other is expressable by $f$ and an elementary function? (the latter seems a bit hopeless, but I may be overpessimistic)

Comment: @H.H.Rugh I have been looking for your second option because general case $y''(x)=ay^3(x)+by^2(x)+cy(x)$ cannot be solved by elementary functions.  Thus I thought that we may overcome this to add a non-elementary function $f(x)$ in elementary function set. However , I do not have a proof yet if it is enough to solve the general case or not. Best Regards

Comment: Ok, got the point. Reading your question posed it seems that you don't have any example yet?

Comment: @ Mathlover Riccati equations, among tough ones to find closed forms..

Answer (score 1):

In general you need to go into elliptic integrals. Set $v=\frac{dy}{dx}$ so that (I add a constant as well to the ode):
$$ y'' = \frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{dv}{dy} \; \frac{dy}{dx} = v \frac{dv}{dy} = ay^3 + by^2 + cy+d$$
In other words,
$$ v dv = (a y^3 + b y^2 + cy) dy$$
Thus, $$ \frac12 \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2 = \frac12 v^2 = \frac{a}{4} y^4+\frac{b}{4} y^3+\frac{c}{2} y^2+d y + e$$
from which taking square root etc you derive the usual elliptic integrals for $x$:
$$ x(y) = \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt {a/2\; y^4 + 2b/3\; y^3 + c \; y^2 + 2dy +2e}}$$
(perhaps use another normalization of constants?).
 Does this correspond to what you had in mind?

Comment: I know this reality very well.  The hardness starts after this.  Please find a transform  (if it is possible) to use a selected elliptic function such as $f(x)$ I selected in my question and find a particular solution for the general case. Thanks for hint

Comment: Ok, I was aware that it didn't answer your question about how to go about for specific functions (but it was a bit too long for a comment). I'll add to the post if I come up with something.

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks a lot for your time and contribution.